# shold i use htmlspecialchars in laravel at input?

Tags: laravel, htmlspecialchars

In Laravel 10 i have a userController with a function like this:

```
public function login(Request $request){    
    
    $userInputs = $request->validate([
        'username' => ['required', 'max:100', 'exists:users,username'],
    ]);

    //more code ....
}
```

but i noticed with this users can bring things like this in the database:

```
<script> alert("hacked"); </script>
```

this is not further problematic since blade escapes the input with the  htmlspecialchars function with the {{ }}.

But i don't like the idea that there is something bad in may database.
Maybe i need to debug something later in my app and i forget about that.

So i tried to implement the htmlspecialchars function into my code.
But, when i use it after the validate function where it checks if the username exists in the database 'exists:users,username' and then save it in the database the 'exists:users,username' function would not work anymore.

But implementation in validation is not planned. But it would need to be executed before the validation. I also would like to have all the validation in the validation function and not something that i would have to write before.

How would you do that?
Or would you even use the htmlspecialchars function before you save it to the database?

Comment: With usernames, specifically, you might consider limiting the usernames your users can *create* in the first place to an acceptable set of characters.

Comment: *"this is not further problematic [...] with the `{{ }}`"* - This is why it's not necessary to sanitize _all_ user input. As long as you don't use `{!! !!}`, that `<script>` tag will only ever be output as plain text. This is a common issue when you're doing RTE (Rich Text Editing), like a description field that supports HTML and/or Markdown. Adding that `<script>` tag to that field, then outputting it via `{!! !!}` would allow that `alert()` to function. So it mainly comes down to use cases, and the golden rule that you should never trust user input and use safe coding practices.

Comment: (and in the case of a rich-text editor, something like https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html to only permit *acceptable* HTML tags *during output* is the way to go)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation) to validate your login, and also use it to convert the username before it's validated. You would create the FormRequest as shown in the documentation, then add this function to the FormRequest:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        // We are exploding the role field from `role-1` to `role` and `1`
        'username' => htmlspecialchars($this->username)
    ]);
}
```